# Is there a way of reading a block of text and manipulating parts of it?

Tags: java, android, c

I want to read a block text from an ***EditText*** or from a ***Database*** and use portions of it to perform various actions

---

*e.g.* **1.** If the text in the ***EditText*** is **"192.168.137.1"**
I want to store each of the octets as different integer values from which I can use for calculations.

**2.** If a Database returns a Time String in the following format ***YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS***
I want to use it *for example* in the code below.

```
Date data = new Date(year, month, day);
Time data = new Time(hour, min, sec);
```

As of now I use four ***EditText*** to get an IP Address but I want just a single ***EditText*** to get a full IPv4 Address

---

My main problem is how to separate the strings and store them as *say* different int values

## Please is there any way to do this in Android Java and C.
I need code that will do it.

Comment: You can use "split()" method of the String class. It will give you back a string[]. You can handle each string according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the IP Adress, use

```
String ip= editText.getText().toString();
String[] octets = ip.split();
int [] integerOctets = new int[octets.length];
for(int i=0; i<octets.length;i++)
  integerOctets[i]=Integer.parseInt(octets[i]);
```

So the octets will be stored on the integerOctets[].

For the Time String, you can use:

```
String []dateTime= editText.getText().toString().split(" ");
String [] dates=dateTime[0].split("-");
int year=dates[0];
int month=dates[1];
int day=dates[2];
String[]times=dateTime[1].split(":");
int hour=times[0];
int min=times[1];
int sec=times[2];
```

Comment: Check my edited answer